# Tailwind CSS IntelliSense for VS Code gives me suggestions from another project

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I have two different projects, both in separate folders with their own tailwind.config.js file. While working on the second project, the plugin is still giving me suggestions from the first project when I type in a color for example. Below is is directory structure:

```
--projects
---project a
---- tailwind config
---project b
----tailwind config
```

Any tips to solve my issue? Thanks!